# How to bind and parse HTML content retrieved from database via Json

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8.

I'm trying to bind `{{card.reading}}` in the view, but the data is rendered as text

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="postController as tarot">
  <ul>
   <li class="card" ng-repeat="card in tarot">
      <img class="card" src="app/images/cards/{{card.value}}.png" alt="card.name">
      <article>{{card.reading | unsafe}}</article>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApplication', []);
    app.controller('postController', function($scope, $http, $filter, $sce) {
    $scope.$sce = $sce;
    var url = './api.php/tarot';
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
    $scope.tarot = php_crud_api_transform(response).tarot; 
    });
  });
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce){
   return $sce.parseAsHtml;
});
```

**exemple of JSON**

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name": "Test",
 "value": "1",
 "reading": "<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2><p>Lorem ipsum</p>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your HTML as such should do the trick..

```
<div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="postController as tarot">
      <ul>
       <li class="card" ng-repeat="card in tarot">
          <img class="card" src="app/images/cards/{{card.value}}.png" alt="card.name">
          <article ng-bind-html="card.reading"></article>
       </li>
      </ul>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it's solved now.

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApplication', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce',
        function postController($scope, $http, $sce) {

            var url = './api.php/tarot';

            $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                $scope.tarot = php_crud_api_transform(response).tarot
            });
            $scope.explicitlyTrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml();
        }
    ]);
```

and the HTML as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution . you can modify you code a little bit and it will work.

```
<div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="postController as tarot">
 <ul>
  <li class="card" ng-repeat="card in tarot">
   <img class="card" src="app/images/cards/{{card.value}}.png"   alt="card.name">
  <article ng-bind-html="card.reading | unsafe"></article>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>`
```

change your filter to ,

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        }
    });
```

This will work.